# Set Multiple Default Values for People/Group Picker

Tags: infopath, active-directory, user-accounts

I have a scenario where I would like to set the default values of a people picker to a handful of users based on information in the form. However, if I set the `AccountID` of the field to a concatenated string of the usernames `DOMAIN\account1; DOMAIN\account2; DOMAIN\account3` InfoPath tries to validate the string as being one username.

Is there any way around this? Is it possible to somehow dynamically set multiple default values for a people/group picker?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choices are seperated in SharePoint using `;#` instead of `;`. Setting your default value to `DOMAIN\account1;#DOMAIN\account2;#DOMAIN\account3` should allow you to set multiple default values.

Alternatively there appears to be a solution posted on Technet ([link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92175d33-18a8-4514-8c5b-6a4f0bc3448b/set-people-picker-field-with-multiple-selections?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)) that may work.

In case the link doesn't work in future here's the contents of that:

> Hi Thank you for responding. Sorry for not being as clear as I hoped
>   to be.
>
> List A is a customized form library with the people picker as a
>   promoted field from the form. Not build from the library. List B is a
>   document library, and I am actually creating a new item in this
>   library where my default content type is a customized document set.
>
> So my workflow creates an item in the doc library, which is by default
>   a document set. I then set the properties of the document set from the
>   work flow like you show above. But instead of UPDATE, I am using
>   CREATE. This works perfectly fine and how I want it to, except for the
>   people picker with multiple selections.
>
> I found a work around where I have a text field with a default value
>   (done in InfoPath)
>
> xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(/my:myFields/my:PeoplePicker/pc:Person,
>   'concat(pc:AccountId, "; ")'), "..") This sets the text field with the
>   multiple users with the display name. I then use this field to set the
>   people picker, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @user1513697 Which soloution worked for you? @Codingo's comment about the using of " `;#` instead of `;` " or the Technet reference? I'm running into the same issue and  concatenating my `AccountID`s with the `;#` isn't working.